# What are some powerful computer sound systems with easy setup?

Tags: sound-system

For the longest time I've had the old [Logitech Z313](http://www.logitech.com/en-us/product/speaker-system-z313?crid=1589) 2.1 sound system for my computer. After so many years of use and moving around, I'm looking for a more portable and more powerful system.

The Z313's wiring is aggravating. The 3.5mm from the computer goes into a controller, then to the sub, then to the speakers. Also, the sub doesn't have a control to turn bass down independently from the speakers.

So what I'm looking for is a sound system with these features:

- no more than $150
- 2.1 layout
- subwoofer with: independent control, 20+ Watts, ~6 inch external driver
- 2+ inch speaker driver
- flat-bottomed subwoofer would be better than one with feet
- easy setup, not too many cords (very important)

An inline or onboard volume control is actually something I don't want since I can control volume with my keyboard and directly in Windows, but if a good system has it, I won't mind.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are willing to wait, you could get the [Logitech Z333 Multimedia Speakers](http://www.logitech.com/en-us/product/multimedia-speakers-z333?crid=1589). As this hasn't been released yet, I can only go off of the spec sheet and online reviews, but this looks like it would fit your needs.

This is a 2.1 speaker system that costs $80 USD. The subwoofer is flat-bottomed, has its own independent controller, and has a 5 inch, front facing driver. The sub is rated at 23 Watts while the two satellites are rated at 8 Watts each. While the website doesn't say exactly how big the drivers are for the satellites, the width of the satellites is about 4.25 inches, so I would expect the drivers are in the range of 2.5 - 3.5 inches in diameter. There are four 5 foot cables for this system (plus input cables): one for the power (wall to sub), one for each satellite (sub to satellite), and one volume controller (controller to sub).

This system has both a 3.5 mm auxiliary input and stereo RCA inputs.

With about half of your budget left, you add a [Bluetooth Audio Adapter](http://www.logitech.com/en-us/product/bluetooth-audio-adapter?WT.ac=ps|11380|bluetoothaudioadapter-CTA1) for $40 that allows you to stream music from any Bluetooth enabled audio device. With both of these items, you are still below your $150 budget (excluding shipping).

---

**UPDATE**

This appears to have been released. If ordered from Logitech's website, you will get free standard shipping (4-7 business days) on this as the total cost is over $49.

Comment: That looks like an amazing system. Pretty much everything I want. I'll definitely keep my eye on it.

Comment: @Adam The only problem with it is when it gets released. I haven't found anything consistent with the date. I will update this answer with more information when I find it.

Answer (score 3):

I recently had the same problem and in the end went for the [Soundsticks III from Harman Kardon](http://m.harmankardon.com/computer-speakers/SOUNDSTICKS+III.html). They look and sound beautiful. Sub is on feet though, but gives a really tight sound.

I got mine for €100 (around $120).

It has the following features:

- Price around €99 (at least [here in holland](http://www.bol.com/nl/p/harman-kardon-soundsticks-iii-2-1-speakerset-transparant/9000000011756073/))
- 2.1 layout
- Subwoofer with: independent control, 20+ Watts, 6 inch external driver
- Subwoofer in on feet.
- Four, 1" full-range transducers per channel powered by a 10-watt
  amplifier for room-filling sound
- Touch volume and mute controls
- Angle-adjustable satellites
- Easy setup, one chord from every speaker to the subwoofer, a mini-jack input for connecting your device and a power input connected to the subwoofer.

Comment: I've heard that's a great system, but the look is just too much for me. I'm a minimalistic kind of person.

Comment: Hi jazz! This answer could be improved if you could list some of the features that your product holds. Otherwise, I like the Soundsticks as well :)

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I added some features to the post